# Callback return empty array js

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, node.js, callback

Here is the function with in sql queries call.
I need return callback only after all queries done.
But it return an empty array
How to return array with data after all?
`

```
function getUserSales(days, callback){
  getUserByLastLoginDay(days, function (users) {
    var userArray = [];
    _.each(users, function (user) {
      getMostFavoredCat(user.id, function (cat) {
        if(!cat || cat.length == 0){
         return false;
        } else {
          user.mostFavoredCat = takeMostRepeatingObj(cat);
        }
        getRelatedSaleByCat(user.id, user.mostFavoredCat.id, function (sales) {
          user.sales = sales;
          userArray.push(user)
        })
      })
    })
    callback(userArray);
  })
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

callback function first parameter is always an error

```
callback(null,userArray)
```

you can make use of async.js for the better control flow

`npm i async --save`

```
const async = require('async');

function getUserSales(days, callback){
  getUserByLastLoginDay(days, function (users) {
    var userArray = [];
    async.each(users, function (user, cb) {
      getMostFavoredCat(user.id, function (cat) {
        if(!cat || cat.length == 0){
         return false;
        } else {
          user.mostFavoredCat = takeMostRepeatingObj(cat);
        }
        getRelatedSaleByCat(user.id, user.mostFavoredCat.id, function (sales) {
          user.sales = sales;
          userArray.push(user)
          cb();
        })
      })
    }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, userArray);
        }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i know. And it did not help any way

Comment: does `userArray` contain the data, please can you put the `getUserSales` function call

Comment: so i put callback(null, userArray) it still return me empty array.

Comment: first your callback should be `callback(null, userArray)` it's returning null due to the asynchronous nature of node.js, just do a `console.log(userArray)` before the `callback()`, i am sure it will print `[]`

Comment: yes, indeed. the callback return [] before my query will end. I need vice versa, only after query is done, return callback.

Comment: yes,  but now i have another issue with sql queries and each loop. the problem is that sqlQueries repeat all each user and only after it going to the callback. i need vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will Works:

```
function getUserSales(days, callback){
 getUserByLastLoginDay(days, function (users) {
   var userArray = [];
   _.each(users, function (user) {
      getMostFavoredCat(user.id, function (cat) {
       if(!cat || cat.length == 0){
       return false;
    } else {
      user.mostFavoredCat = takeMostRepeatingObj(cat);
    }
    getRelatedSaleByCat(user.id, user.mostFavoredCat.id, function (sales) {
      user.sales = sales;
      userArray.push(user)
    })
  })
callback(userArray);
})
})
}
```